# How to check if a value exists in a list, and store the elements that include it in variables

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to make an encrypter, where it shifts the letter 3 times (so A becomes D, B becomes E, etc.)
Then X goes back to A, Y to B, and Z to C. I'm using ASCII values to shift them. I'm trying to see if any part of the list has the ASCII values of X, Y, or Z, then if yes, change that element back to A, B, or C's ASCII value.
I know you can check if there is a value in a list, but how do I actually take this value and change it? Here is what I'm trying to do:

- Check if X/Y/Z's ASCII code exists in the user_input list
- If true, get that value and change it back into A/B/C's ASCII value accordingly.
  Here is my code:

```
def encrypt(userInput):
    #Find Ascii Value of plaintext
    asciiValue = [ord(c) for c in userInput]
    #Convert Ascii value (list) into integers
    intAscii = [int(x) for x in asciiValue]

    encryptedAscii = [n + 3 for n in intAscii]
    if '120' in encryptedAscii:
        encryptedAscii = '97'
    elif '121' in encryptedAscii:
        encryptedAscii = '98'
    elif '122' in encryptedAscii:
        encryptedAscii = '99'
    else:
        encryptedOutput = ''.join(chr(v) for v in encryptedAscii)
    return encryptedOutput
```

Thanks!

Comment: obviously this won't work:
if '120' in encryptedAscii:
        encryptedAscii = '97'
    elif '121' in encryptedAscii:
        encryptedAscii = '98'
    elif '122' in encryptedAscii:
        encryptedAscii = '99'
but i can't figure out how to do it right...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually don't need to check for `x, y, z` separately. Just use the modulo operator (`%`) so if it overflows, it will turn back to `a, b, c`:

```
def encrypt(userInput):
    # Find Ascii Value of plaintext
    asciiValue = [ord(c) for c in userInput]
    # Convert Ascii value (list) into integers
    intAscii = [int(x) - 97 for x in asciiValue]

    encryptedAscii = [(n + 3) % 26 + 97 for n in intAscii]
    encryptedOutput = ''.join(chr(v) for v in encryptedAscii)
    return encryptedOutput

from string import ascii_lowercase
print(encrypt(ascii_lowercase))
```

Output:

```
defghijklmnopqrstuvwxyabc
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `ord` and `chr` is fine, but there is also an easier method: [str.maketrans](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.maketrans) and [str.translate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate):

```
from string import ascii_uppercase as ABC, ascii_lowercase as abc

def encrypt(text, tr):
    return text.translate(tr)

# join translation dicts for ABCD and abcs to 
# create mapping from 2 strings of equal lenght, 
# first is "from" second is "to" mapping:  
tr = {**str.maketrans(abc, abc[3:]+abc[:3]),     # lower case a-z
      **str.maketrans(ABC, ABC[3:]+ABC[:3])}     # upper case A-Z

text = "ABCDEFGXYZabcdefgxyz"
print(text, " => ", encrypt(text,tr))
```

Output:

```
ABCDEFGXYZabcdefgxyz  =>  DEFGHIJABCdefghijabc
```

Comment: I've never used `str.maketrans` so this is an interesting approach for me. However, "abc" should become "def". It remains as "abc" according to your solution.

Comment: @Asocia - edited again - now Z maps to C and z to c :) - the translation dict i used at first only had capital letters in it (ascii_uppercase)